# Plotting and Analyzing Large Network Dataset with R or SparkR

Tags: r, apache-spark, networking, sparkr

I am trying to plot and analyze a network of political contributions by creating weighted links between several hundred politicians and their campaign contributors (in which the weight is the amount of money donated). So far I have manipulated the data so that I have an edge list with the politician id, the donor id, and the amount:

```
pol_id     don_id     amt 
P00003392  C00344531  $188,000.00
P00003392  C00348540  $168,359.00
P00003392  C00589507  $12,000.00
P80001571  C90016221  $654,835.25
```

The problem is that there are 170,000 rows, which is too large for a single computer to process at once. I am somewhat familiar with Spark and know that it can be used to filter and manipulate larger quantities of data, but have never seen it used on network data. Does anyone know how this could be done or have any recommendations for alternative software or methods?

On a smaller scale, using only one politician filtered out from the dataset, this is my code for creating a network object and plotting it using the igraph method:

```
filtered_df <- index %>% filter(can_id == "P00003392")
df2 <- filtered_df %>% as.matrix()
g=graph.edgelist(df2[,1:2], directed=TRUE)
E(g)$weight=as.numeric(df2[,3])
plot(g,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold,edge.width=E(g)$weight/2)
```

I am new to StackOverflow, so please let me know of this question needs clarification or can be improved.

Comment: You might want to investigate Neo4j

Comment: I really like visNetwork in R. And you should be fine with filtering 170k rows with SparkR, collecting the data, and generating a dataset needed for visNetwork with just a couple of additional steps.